How to apply Atlaskit CSS styles to Atlassian Forge Custom UI app?
In want to integrate Atlaskit UI components to my Forge Custom UI App.
I have sucessfully installed specific components via npm and can access them in my static frontend sources, however, the components does not inherit the Atlaskit CSS styles.
My package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "my-forge-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@atlaskit/button": "^17.17.1",
    "@atlaskit/css-reset": "^6.9.0",
    "@atlaskit/eslint-plugin-design-system": "^10.4.3",
    "@atlaskit/form": "^10.2.0",
    "@atlaskit/heading": "^2.3.0",
    "@atlaskit/select": "^17.10.0",
    "@atlaskit/side-navigation": "^3.1.1",
    "@atlaskit/textfield": "^6.3.1",
    "@atlaskit/theme": "^12.8.0",
    "@atlaskit/tokens": "^1.49.1",
    "@forge/bridge": "3.4.0",
    "@forge/react": "^10.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "react": "^16",
    "react-dom": "^16",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]

I have integrated @atlaskit/css-reset to my top-level index.js file:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import '@atlaskit/css-reset';
import { AtlaskitThemeProvider } from '@atlaskit/theme';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <AtlaskitThemeProvider mode="light">
            <App />
        </AtlaskitThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

While I can access the components in my static frontend, they do not inherit the Atlaskit CSS styles.
What else do I need to do?
Best Valentin
